# Honor 6x Bootloop, works sometimes with charger plugged

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, huawei

I have a Honor 6x which was working fine till yesterday. Now it just keeps restarting all of a sudden and works fine sometimes only with the charger plugged in. It restarts every 1-2 second.

Things I've done:

- Removed the cache, nothing happened.
- Did a Hard reset, worked but showed Data partition has damaged
  seriously error.
- tried flashing rom through dload, software install failed.
- tried extracting the upadate.app using Huawei update extractor and
  flashed them, received command not allowed error.

The phone is locked, FRP is locked, Bootloader is locked and not rooted. Also, I can only access the recovery/dload menu once in hundred tries.
With the charger plugged in, either the eRecovery menu loads by itself or phone starts normally but restarts on its own after few minutes(I made a full backup in those few minutes).
Any solution?

Comment: Remove the external SD card and see. It worked for me on Honor 6

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks but I don't use one, I'd used one just for the purpose of force flashing the firmware and currently, is out of the phone.